# jQuery .hover() and page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="foo">
...
    <div id="bar" class="container hidden">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I use Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I added the hidden class to automatically hide the second div by default.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").hover(
        function() {
            $("#bar", this).toggleClass("hidden");
        }, function() {
            $("#bar", this).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

It seems to work correctly BUT if the mouse if already hover the #foo div during the page load, it applies by default the hover effect. After that if I move the mouse outside the #foo div, it applies again the toggleClass and displays the inner #bar div.

How to prevent this behaviour on page load?

Comment: Is it within `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: yeah, could you try that?

Comment: Context selector is useless here, id should be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one mention it but hover pseudo event accept in/out handler, so you could toggle class:

```
$("#foo").hover(function () {
    $("#bar").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

And as IDs must be unique on document context, no need to pass context, just target element with ID.

Answer (score 4):

This is a proper way to do it:

```
$("#foo").hover(
    function() {
        $("#bar", this).addClass("hidden");
    }, function() {
        $("#bar", this).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer you are looking for :) Beat me too it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `toggleClass()` try using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`:

```
$("#foo").hover(

    function() {

        $("#bar", this).addClass("hidden");
    }, function() {

        $("#bar", this).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

This way allows you to have a more precise control over the elements.